# Conversion failed when converting nvarchar value to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

What is the error here? I got an error. but lblStage get the stage value. But error comes.

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct (stage) from tblStatus where EstimateID=@EstimateID", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EstimateID", listEstimateID.Text);
    lblStage.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

Comment: Convert your `listEstimateID.Text` to int

Comment: then it comes "input string was not in the correct format. but still the answer comes. "

Comment: whats the value of `listEstimateID.Text` when it goes to DB?. Also, refer the link to send the parameter value - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You need to provide more details then. Before that, Check your table column data type  with the corresponding value which you enter in. Somewhere the data type mismatch occurs.

Comment: Lol. `AddWithValue("EstimateID"`.. nope.  `AddWithValue("@EstimateID"` ... yes.  Examine your code carefully before asking.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @JK look at [`SqlParameter.ParameterNameFixed`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs,e0b0ddfdcb0fca98) that parameter is used when talking to SQL, if you don't put a @ on it puts one on for you.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. but the thing is there is an event fire in the form load. in the first load all the values do no loaded. so i used a flag and make it "true" in the event. now it is working.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a global parameter and set it false. 
bool isloaded = false;

In the form load make it true
isloaded = true;

```
    private void listEstimateID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isloaded)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct (stage) from tblStatus where EstimateID=@EstimateID", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EstimateID", Convert.ToInt32(listEstimateID.Text));
                lblStage.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct (stage) from tblStatus where EstimateID=@EstimateID", con);

    int id;

    if(int.TryParse(listEstimateID.Text, out id)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EstimateID", id );
    }
    else  MessageBox.Show("Invalid Estimate ID");

    lblStage.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding values for parameters, there should be `@ParameterName` in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct (stage) from tblStatus where EstimateID=@EstimateID", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstimateID", Convert.ToInt32(listEstimateID.Text));
    lblStage.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

See if this works.